# OpenCV Number OCR - Image progressing (Filterin)

Tags: c++, opencv

I success fully cleaned image but there is problem when I clean it with inRange I got error on cvtColor here is my code:

```
    // generate_data.cpp

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// global variables ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 20;
const int MAX_CONTOUR_AREA = 75;

const int RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20;
const int RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat redFilter(const Mat& src)
{
    assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);

    Mat redOnly;
    inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(0, 0, 0), redOnly);

    return redOnly;
}

int main() {

    cv::Mat matTrainingNumbers;     // input image
    cv::Mat matGrayscale;           // 
    cv::Mat matBlurred;             // declare various images
    cv::Mat matThresh;              //
    cv::Mat matThreshCopy;          //

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > ptContours;        // declare contours vector
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> v4iHierarchy;                    // declare contours hierarchy

    cv::Mat matClassificationInts;      // these are our training classifications, note we will have to perform some conversions before writing to file later

                                        // these are our training images, due to the data types that the KNN object KNearest requires,
    cv::Mat matTrainingImages;                  // we have to declare a single Mat, then append to it as though it's a vector,
                                                // also we will have to perform some conversions before writing to file later

                                                // possible chars we are interested in are digits 0 through 9, put these in vector intValidChars
    std::vector<int> intValidChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    matTrainingNumbers = cv::imread("training_numbers.png");            // read in training numbers image
    if (matTrainingNumbers.empty()) {                           // if unable to open image
        std::cout << "error: image not read from file\n\n";     // show error message on command line
        return(0);                                              // and exit program
    }

    matTrainingNumbers = cv::Scalar::all(255) - matTrainingNumbers; // tranfsorm to inverse

     matTrainingNumbers = redFilter(matTrainingNumbers);    // Convert all colors to black

     matTrainingNumbers = cv::Scalar::all(255) - matTrainingNumbers; // tranfsorm to inverse

     cv::imshow("Cleared numbers", matTrainingNumbers);


    cv::cvtColor(matTrainingNumbers, matGrayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY);        // convert to grayscale - problem is here
```

Rest of the code is so long so I dont paste it if any one wants it I can add.

Here images that im progressing

[image: Here which image is entering]

TO:
[image]

Finally error is:assertion failed (scn == 3 scn == 4) in cvtcolor

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error, please.

According to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20inRange(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20lowerb,%20InputArray%20upperb,%20OutputArray%20dst)):

> **C++**: void **inRange**(InputArray src, InputArray lowerb, InputArray upperb, OutputArray dst)
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - ...
> - **dst** – output array of the same size as src and **CV_8U** type.

Your `dst` image is single-channel. `cvtColor` with `CV_BGR2GRAY` expects a BGR image as input.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new in OpenCV. How can I make this BGR image or Is there a way ?